# UIView animation snaps back to original state before transitioning to a new view

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have some UIButtons that I'm animating indefinitely. The buttons all have 3 sublayers that are added, each of which have their own animation. I'm initializing these animations on `viewDidAppear` which works great - they fade in and start rotating. The problem is that when I transition to a new view, the animations seem to "snap" back to their initial state, then back to some other state right before the transition occurs. I've tried explicitly removing all of the animations on viewWillDisappear, even tried hiding the entire UIButton itself, but nothing seems to prevent this weird snapping behavior from occurring.

Here's a gif of what's happening (this is me transitioning back and forth between two views):

[image]

```
func animateRotation() {
// Gets called on viewDidAppear

    let rotationRight: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationRight.toValue = Double.pi * 2
    rotationRight.duration = 4
    rotationRight.isCumulative = true
    rotationRight.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    rotationRight.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    rotationRight.fillMode = .forwards

    let rotationLeft: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
    rotationLeft.toValue = Double.pi * -2
    rotationLeft.duration = 3
    rotationLeft.isCumulative = true
    rotationLeft.repeatCount = Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude
    rotationLeft.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    rotationLeft.fillMode = .forwards

    let circleImage1 = UIImage(named: "circle_1")?.cgImage
    circleLayer1.frame = self.bounds
    circleLayer1.contents = circleImage1
    circleLayer1.add(rotationRight, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer1)

    let circleImage2 = UIImage(named: "circle_2")?.cgImage
    circleLayer2.frame = self.bounds
    circleLayer2.contents = circleImage2
    circleLayer2.add(rotationLeft, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer2)

    let circleImage3 = UIImage(named: "circle_3")?.cgImage
    circleLayer3.frame = self.bounds
    circleLayer3.contents = circleImage3
    circleLayer3.add(rotationRight, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer3)
}
```

I would think something as simple as this would hide the button completely as soon as it knows it's going away:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    animatedButton.isHidden = true
}
```

What's also interesting is that this seems to stop happening if I let it run for a couple minutes. This tells me that it might be some sort of race condition. Just not sure what that race might be...

Comment: When transitioning to a new view, do you mean going to a new screen and coming back? Have you tried calling animateRotation() in ViewDidLoad()? is it necessary for it to be in viewDidAppear()?

Comment: It works fine when entering the view with the animation. The strange behavior that I'm seeing is immediately *before* leaving the screen with the animation active. So I tap on the button to leave the screen, the animation flashes, and then the screen transitions out to the next view.

Comment: Can you show the code that gets triggered when the button is tapped? Trying to understand how your view controller is structured. So the animation is always visible when the screen loads? It might be useful to also show a gif of you tapping on the button so I can understand how your view looks and works. It seems like the animation is running multiple times at the same time.

Comment: @AlecSanger "What's also interesting is that this seems to stop happening if I let it run for a couple minutes." I wonder if that has anything to do with ".duration" attribute of your animations. Maybe try setting the duration to 15 seconds and see if the bug happens before the 15 seconds but not after.

Comment: Nothing actually occurs when the button is tapped - you can consider these plain UIViews with images applied as sublayers. When setting the animation to only run once, the rotation properly stops in the final resting place (1 full rotation). When navigating away from the screen, there is no flicker because the flicker is going between the current animation position and the original position of the layers. These are the same if I let the animation complete.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the UIView set of animations they set the actual state to the final state and then start the animation, ie:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { view.alpha = 0 }
```

If you check alpha right after the animation starts, it's already 0.

This is a convenience that UIView does for you but that CALayer does not.  When you set a CALayer animation you are only setting the animation value, not the actual value of the variable, so when the animation is done, the layer snaps back to its original value.  Check the layer value while you are in the middle of the animation and you will see the real value has not changed; only the animated value in the presentation layer has changed.

If you want to replicate the UIView behavior you need to either set the actual final value not he layer when the animation begins or in the use the delegate to set it when the animation ends.

Comment: All of what you said makes complete sense, and I was pretty sure that your suggestion would fix the problem. However I went ahead and replaced my 3 separately animated sublayers with a single rotating UIButton with a single image applied to it using UIView.animate + self.transform, and I'm *still* seeing the same behavior. That tells me that this isn't related to the CALayer.